# Logging custom message to Azure Monitor or App Insights from Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We need to log custom messages into Azure Monitor or AppInsights from Data Factory, including pipelines. For example, a pipeline runs validation and requires to log a validation error for a file with an exceeded length of the file name and carry on running the rest of the pipeline.

The loggings are viewable from Azure Monitor.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To extract data from **AppInsights** and run a query of AppInsights in **Azure Data Factory**. You could use **Web Activity** in the ADF to invoke the Application Insights REST API after the execution of your main activities.

**Or**

You can use [**Azure Monitor**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#configure-diagnostic-settings-and-workspace) instead of Application Insights.

For more details, please **refer** to this document:

https://www.ben-morris.com/using-azure-data-factory-with-the-application-insights-rest-api/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api